# Passing Data Between two ViewControllers in MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I recently started exploring MVVM and stuck at passing data between 2 view controllers.I have an array of items in my viewModel1 of ViewController1 and I want to pass that array to viewcontroller2. I am able to achieve it by getting the whole array from viewModel1 like below but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == Constants.kShowDetailSegue {
        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! ListViewController
        destinationViewController.products = viewModel1.getFavouriteProducts()
      //the getFavouriteProducts gets data from coredata.

    }
}
```

Comment: It is a commonly used pattern of passing data so there is nothing wrong/bad with it. 
It works fine, right? You want to pass an array, your `ListViewController` gets the array.

Comment: thanks for the reply.I dont think what I am doing is following MVVM properly. I dont want the array in viewcontroller2 to be exposed to viewcontroller1

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done it the right way, but alternatively you can use closures. Which are the preferred, method of communication within iOS. You will take care of memory leaks wherever necessary by using

```
weak
```

OR

unowned